# How can I monitor failed SSH login attempts and view the password that was used?

Tags: linux, ssh

For testing purposes, I need to know what password was used while attempting to SSH into a server - failed attempts only. I want to implement this on the server side.

Is this possible? How can I do this?

I'm using SUSE Linux VERSION="12-SP5".

Comment: I found [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/465378/108618), but I cannot really tell how good it is. Anyway, it shows a possible way. I agree with [this comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/199572/108618#comment335280_199572): "not something that even should be possible as this leaks any passwords that are entered with as little mistake as a single typo".

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski, I'm giving it a try at the moment. 

getting the following error on step #7

root@rcm:/opt/openssh2/zlib-1.2.11/#: ./configure --prefix=${OPENSSH}/dist/ && make && make install
Checking for gcc...
Compiler error reporting is too harsh for ./configure (perhaps remove -Werror).
** ./configure aborting.